# TreeViewer setSelectionProvider works only for one control

Tags: java, eclipse, jface

I am trying to create Eclipse Plugin which have a composite with two TreeViewer side by side. I have used setSelectionProvider() to register them with Workbench in order to show the property for selected node of Treeviewer in eclipse Property view. The problem I am facing is that at a time only 1 TreeViewer can be registered to the workbench. How can I resolve this problem?
Thanks, Tor

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by implementing `ISelectionProvider` yourself and delegating the selection events of both trees to the registered listeners. `getSelection()` could return the last selection that has been made in either one of your trees. I'm not sure how `setSelection(ISelection selection)` could be implemented in a sensible manner, though. I'd probably let it throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` unless you're sure that this method is actually required in this context.

Comment: hi. I created a new class implementing ISelectionProvider interface. Now how to use this for adding treeviewer setselection provider component? thanks, tor

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand what you're trying to do now.